# Getting data from jQuery Draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have some code that looks like this:

```
<div id="playlist1" class="playlist-row ui-draggable" style="position: relative; ">
<input type="hidden" id="playid" value="48">
<div class="playlist-name">american</div>
<div class="playlist-type">media</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

See where it says 48? How can I get that information to pass through a function upon it being dropped? I just thought a hidden input would be best but clearly not as it isnt working. Keep in mind 48 is a variable called playlists[j]. When I try now I get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [jQuery Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) for drag-and-drop functionality.  Tap into the [drop event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop)'s callback function if you want to run code once the item has been dropped.

Comment: I have a droppable zone with a drop function ready to go. I just don't know how to access the information I want from the draggable part.

Comment: The drop event takes a function which allows for two parameters.  I believe the `ui` parameter is the original object.  Use an inspector on those parameters to see which it is.